# how to use only strings to pull json data

Tags: python, json

So I keep running into a issue where json is asking to use a int to find pieces of data in a json response. Below is the code that works though the issue is i want to print every 'name' in the json though id have to change the [0] to 1 and then 2 ect. I tried to increment it though that ran into issue too. This could be just me overlooking something but let me know, thanks.

```
def BaseTesting(TarLink):
    PayloadToSend = {
        
    }
    HeadersToSend = { # make sure to change your token at least once every 30 mins
        'authorization': '',
        'user-agent': ''
    }
    ReqForFriends = requests.post(TarLink, headers=HeadersToSend, data=PayloadToSend).text

    LoadedJSONData = json.loads(ReqForFriends)
    print(LoadedJSONData['friends'][0]['name'])

BaseTesting(TarLink="")
```

JSON

```
{
   "friends":[
      {
         "name":"test1",
         "user_id":"1132",
         "type":2,
         "display":"true",

      },
      {
         "name":"test2",
         "user_id":"2341",
         "type":1,
         "display":"true",

      },
      {
         "name":"test3",
         "user_id":"1234",
         "type":2,
         "display":"true",

      },
}
```

Comment: Iterating over the list "LoadedJSONData['friends']" is the way to go. What issue do you have with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems to work properly

```
LoadedJSONData = {
   "friends":[
      {
         "name":"test1",
         "user_id":"1132",
         "type":2,
         "display":"true",

      },
      {
         "name":"test2",
         "user_id":"2341",
         "type":1,
         "display":"true",

      },
      {
         "name":"test3",
         "user_id":"1234",
         "type":2,
         "display":"true",

      },
    ]
}


for i in range(0,3):
    print(LoadedJSONData['friends'][i]['name']) #test1 test2 test3
```

Comment: there is `[` isn't closed in your JSON

Comment: Seems the way you made it loop in a range made it work, i adjusted the code to just except a IndexError error and it works. Thanks!